# Google Sheets clearing every other cell with a script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a sheet that have formulas on column B at every other Row starting from B3, so it's B3, B5 and up to B101, I have the following script to clear the rest of the sheet except for column B, How can I add to the function to clear every other row from B3 to B101?

```
function ClearCells() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('sheetName');

 sheet.getRange('C3:T102').clearContent();

 sheet.getRange('A3:A102').clearContent();
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please show what you tried to adapt the script to your goal.

Comment: I have a button connected to the script to clear the sheet but keep the formulas in the odd rows of column B starting with B3 to B101

Comment: Hi and welcome to WebApps. Just to be clear, is there any date/formula on the even rows in Column B? You said that you had a script that _keep[s] the formulas in the odd rows of column B starting with B3 to B101_. Why not just delete that part of the script that keeps those formulas?

Comment: Yes, Even cells has formulas,from B4 to B104, I don't have a script to keep those formulas from being cleared, what I need to do is clear only the odd rows and keep the formulas on the even cells, So I need to Clear B3, don't clear B4, clear B5, don't clear B6 and so on, every other row till B104

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
function clearoddrows() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()

  var sheetname = "Sheet1"
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname)

  // get the range B3 to B101
  var startrow = 3
  var endrow = 101
  var column = 2

  // get the range
  var range = sheet.getRange(startrow, 2, (endrow-startrow+1))
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: range = "+range.getA1Notation())

  // get the values
  var values = range.getValues()

  // create a loop, increment by 2 for every other row
  for (var i=0;i<endrow-startrow+1;i=i+2){
    //Logger.log("DEBUG: i:"+i+" value "+values[i][0])

    // clear content
    sheet.getRange(startrow+i,2).clearContent()

  }

}
```

The key is that the loop value increments by 2, so it will affect every other row.

Note: I think that this is an inefficient piece of code. It goes against the grain to perform `getRange()` and `ClearContent()` inside the loop. But it runs quickly and will do until someone dreams up something better ;)

FWIW: I did consider capturing the column data in an array, and then updating the value inside the loop, then `setValues()` after the loop. However, this has the effect of converting formula to values which is unacceptable.

Comment: [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)